# Android MVP with Volley

Tags: android, android-volley, mvp, android-mvp

I have the following problem. I want to implement MVP with Android, using Volley as a model. The problem is, that Volley requestQueue need context. I know that one solution is to make a static Context, but it's a bad practice. How should I create this code with MVP.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

Comment: You should inject the context with a dependency inyection library like Koin or Dagger.

Comment: No, it's not a bad practice. You could make it in your Application class and use it in different places.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to abstract your network request entirely and create a class that handles the network request. You can then create this class when you create it. For example in the Application class where you have the application context.

```
class NetworkRequest(
    private val context: Context
) {
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)

    fun doNetworkRequest() {
        val request = StringRequest(...)
        queue.add(request)
    }
}

class Presenter(
    private val networkRequest: NetworkRequest
) {
    . . .
}
```

In this way you can test your presenter by mocking the NetworkRequest and the implementation detail of requesting to the server is abstracted from your presentation logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I cannot guarantee the correctness of the answer, but it's working.

I changed my Presenter constructor and now I should implicit pass the correct view to the presenter, because in my App start I am passing a fragment, not a view. That's why I created setPresenter method in MainView interface.

```
 public MainPresenter(MainContract.MainView view, NetworkLayer networkLayer) {
    this.view = view;
    this.view.setPresenter(this);
    this.networkLayer = networkLayer;
}
```

Now I am setting the NetworkLayer on App start (in MainActivity or in Application class). There I have an access to the application context and I can pass the network layer without storing a context in presenter. To make the right connection between presenter and model I created a setter in NetworkLayer to pass the right presenter.

```
    MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
    //Inject view and model
    MainContract.MainPresenter mainPresenter = new MainPresenter(mainFragment, NetworkLayer.getInstance(getApplicationContext()));
    NetworkLayer.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setPresenter(mainPresenter);
```